# Installing a new version of a software already installed?

Tags: software-installation, deb, 23.04

So I run Discord on my computer and it doesn't come from a repository, it's a downloaded .deb-file.

Sometimes Discord wants me to update with a new .deb-file.
But when I download and run that deb file "Ubuntu software" (which looks like a skinned GDebi) just shows that Discord is installed and what version the .deb file is.
But instead of asking me if I want to install the new .deb file over the already installed one (which it doesn't list any version information for) it just gives me the option to remove the software.

[image: Image of Are you sure you want to uninstall discord-canary?]

So to install a .deb file I need to first remove the software and then click the .deb file again to install it. Seems overly cumbersome.

Sure, I could just do `dpkg -i <debfile>` but why do we have Ubuntu Software

[image: Image of Ubuntu Software dialog when trying to install new version of discord-canary]

Comment: I see this happening with a few different softwares that come from a 3 rd party as a deb. Nothing to do with the version of Ubuntu have had it since 16.04. You will not like the answer. You need to live with it or stop using that software. Whom ever created the software needs to fix it. I have never had luck getting any of 3 different makers do that.

Comment: But the software that is associated with opening .deb-files doesn't do what it's supposed to. It opens the .deb-file I've downloaded and gives me the option to uninstall it. BUT in reality I'm uninstallning another version of the same software already installed on my system. But ubuntu-software doesn't provide me the information of what that is...

Comment: I tried Gdebi now. That works as expected.It states that "Same version is already installed" and gives me the option to Reinstall or to Remove the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the answer is to NOT use Ubuntu Software to open .deb files.
Use *GDebi* instead. Opening a .deb with GDebi states that "Same version is already installed" and gives me the option to *Reinstall* or to *Remove the package*.

[Pictures of GDebi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnI9f.png)

Answer (score 1):

> So to install a .deb file I need to first remove the software and then click the .deb file again to install it. Seems overly
> cumbersome.

This is just how it works, apparently.

> Sure, I could just do `dpkg -i` but why do we have Ubuntu Software

If you want a version of Discord that automatically updates, you could install the [Snap version](https://snapcraft.io/discord).

To install this, first remove the `.deb` version you have installed. Then either:

1. Go to "Ubuntu Software", search for "Discord" and install it.
2. Run the following from the terminal: `sudo snap install discord`

Afterwards, to enable all features, run this command: `snap connect discord:system-observe`

Comment: Yeah no. There is no way I'm running the Snap-version if the developer supplies me with a .deb file. I won't get any support running a Snap-version.

Answer (score 0):

I simply do

> `sudo apt install <upgrade_file.deb>`

and it replaces the current version pretty well.

Comment: Well sure, we could all just use the command line instead. But that's not the question is it?

Comment: @MårtenWoxberg: Yes, you are right! :) I just wanted to mention a natural alternative for `dpkg -i` that you mentioned in the question.